# What are some examples of moving a fluid changing only its kinetic energy?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, pressure, flow

Bernoulli's principle states that, in a steady, incompressible, inviscid flow, the sum of all forms of mechanical energy in a fluid along a streamline is the same at all points on that streamline. This requires that the sum of the fluid's kinetic energy, gravitational potential energy, and internal energy (i.e. pressure-volume energy) remains constant.

Real fluids are compressible and have viscosity.

What are the common scenarios given in literature or observed in everyday life that produce a fluid flow due to only a change in the fluids kinetic energy? This question supposes that it is possible. If it is not possible, can you explain why not? (E.g., if the kinetic energy changes then so too must the pressure-volume energy because [reasons])

Comment: Decelerating motion of a fluid jet inside the same fluid (for e.g. air-jet issuing from a blower into air) is purely due to loss of fluid's kinetic energy to friction.

Comment: @Deep Good example, it inspired me to think of the following: I suppose if there is open-channel horizontal flow that passes through a converging or diverging section of open-channel (open to atmosphere), the fluid's kinetic energy will change while its pressure and potential energies remain constant?

Comment: There would be pressure changes inside a converging/diverging channel.

Comment: @Deep even when the channel is open to constant pressure? What about the liquid streamline at the liquid-gas interface?

Comment: The pressure would be atmospheric at the interface. But a constant flow through a channel requires a driving pressure gradient to overcome viscous forces. This is true even if the channel is of uniform cross-section.

Comment: @Deep True. So what would occur in this scenario if we make Bernoulli assumptions, namely inviscid flow?

Comment: In that case you don't need a pressure gradient to maintain the flow.